# Is the status of "sexually-active" self-reported by the patients?

Tags: sex, health-education, physiology

In the medical and social research concerning "sexual activity" of man or woman, for example:

> [Can tampon use cause hymen changes in girls who have not had sexual intercourse?](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037907389800053X)
>
> Nevertheless, clefts were found in both the sexually active and the never-active groups: 20 of their 200 never-sexually-active subjects possessed complete hymenal clefts, as did only 84 of their 100 sexually active subjects

Is the status "sexually-active" usually self-reported by the patients? How trustworthy is this data? What if someone misreport their status? What are some mechanisms to prevent lies?

Comment: Did you provide the wrong link? You linked to an article about tampon use by young girls. What does that have to do with your question?

Comment: @CareyGregory The most important variables they studied are related to my title. Just check the abstract

Comment: What other method do you think would be more accurate than self-report?